# Prolog: partition integer list items by their parity

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Write a predicate which takes as input a list of integers, `L`, and produces two lists: the list containing the even elements from `L` and the list of odd elements from `L`.

```
?- separate_parity([1,2,3,4,5,6], Es, Os).
Es = [2,4,6], Os = [1,3,5] ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use structural recursion on lists. Write down the equivalences for each mutually exclusive case:

```
parity_partition([A|B], [A|X], Y):- 0 is A mod 2, parity_partition(B,X,Y).
parity_partition([A|B], X, [A|Y]):- 1 is A mod 2, parity_partition(B,X,Y).
parity_partition([],[],[]).
```

This means: relation `parity_partition(L,E,O)` *holds*,

1. in case `L=[A|B]` and `A` is even, *when* `E=[A|X]`, `O=Y` and relation `parity_partition(B,X,Y)` holds.
2. in case `L=[A|B]` and `A` is odd, *when* `E=X`, `O=[A|Y]` and relation `parity_partition(B,X,Y)` holds.
3. in case `L=[]`, when `E=[]` and `O=[]`.

Just writing down these equivalences gives us the Prolog program to solve this.

---

Operationally, this means: to separate a list `L` into a list of evens `E` and a list of odds `O`,

```
  1. if `L` is a non-empty list `[A|B]`,
     1a.  if `A` is even, 
              allocate new list node for `E=[H|T]`, 
              set its data field `H=A`,
              and continue separating the rest of input list `B`
                           into `T` and `O` ; or
     1b.  if `A` is odd, 
              allocate new list node for `O=[H|T]`, 
              set its data field `H=A`,
              and continue separating the rest of input list `B`
                           into `E` and `T` ; or
  2. if `L` is an empty list, set both `E` and `O` to be empty lists
```

the actual sequence of operations might be a little bit different but conceptually the same:

```
  1. try to unify L=[A|B], E=[A|X]. If not, go to 2. 
     1a. check if A is even. 
         If not, abandon the instantiations made 
                 as part of unifications, and go to 2.
     1b. Continue with B, X, and the same O: use B as L, X as E, and go to 1.
  2. try to unify L=[A|B], O=[A|Y]. If not, go to 3.
     2a. check if A is odd. 
         If not, abandon the instantiations made 
                 as part of unifications, and go to 3.
     2b. Continue with B, Y, and the same E: use B as L, Y as O, and go to 1.
  3. Unify L,E,O with [].
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for this. In this manner you get a pure relation:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
list_evens_odds([], [], []).
list_evens_odds([E|Zs], [E|Es], Os) :-
   0 #= E mod 2,
   list_evens_odds(Zs, Es, Os).
list_evens_odds([E|Zs], Es, [E|Os]) :-
   1 #= E mod 2,
   list_evens_odds(Zs, Es, Os).
```

You can use this not only to split a list into evens and odds. But you can go even further. The following interaction is with SWI, but you get similar in SICStus with `asserta(clpfd:full_answer)`.

```
?- list_evens_odds([1,2,3,4,5,6], Es, Os).
   Es = [2,4,6], Os = [1,3,5]
;  false.
?- Zs = [A,B,C], list_evens_odds(Zs, Es, Os).
   Zs = [A,B,C], Es = [A,B,C], Os = [], A mod 2#=0, B mod 2#=0, C mod 2#=0
;  Zs = [A,B,C], Es = [A,B], Os = [C], A mod 2#=0, B mod 2#=0, C mod 2#=1
;  Zs = [A,B,C], Es = [A,C], Os = [B], A mod 2#=0, B mod 2#=1, C mod 2#=0
;  ... .
?- Es = [E], Os = [O], list_evens_odds(Zs, Es, Os).
   Es = [E], Os = [O], Zs = [E, O], E mod 2#=0, O mod 2#=1
;  Es = [E], Os = [O], Zs = [O, E], E mod 2#=0, O mod 2#=1
;  false.
```

The next is probably most irritating: Here, we ask whether there is an integer `EO` that is both even and odd. Certainly, such an integer cannot exist. But we still get two answers!

```
?- EOs=[EO], list_evens_odds(Zs, EOs, EOs).
   EOs = [EO], Zs = [EO, EO], EO mod 2#=1, EO mod 2#=0
;  EOs = [EO], Zs = [EO, EO], EO mod 2#=0, EO mod 2#=1
;  false.
```

This illustrates the difference between answers and solutions. We get here two answers, but both do not contain a solution. Most of the time an answer contains one or more solutions, but it can also contain none as in this case. Such answers are sometimes called inconsistencies.

Inconsistencies are not necessarily considered a *bug* of an implementation. They are rather an engineering tradeoff: Ensuring consistency might be very costly compared to the actual benefits. And: Prolog does not produce an incorrect answer: For the condition that has to hold is shown. Even if that condition turns out to be false.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915), and reified test [`zodd_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Using `tpartition/4` in combination with `zodd_t/2` we can simply write:

```
?- tpartition(zodd_truth,[1,2,3,4,5,6],Es,Os).
Es = [1,3,5], Os = [2,4,6].                 % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer from @Will Ness is good and detailed. I'll just add the possibility, if your Prolog offers it, to use a 'higher order' builtin (i.e. a predicate that receives a predicate as argument):

```
separate_parity(L, E, O) :-
    partition(is_even, L, E, O).
is_even(N) :- N mod 2 =:= 0.
```

You can find [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=partition/4) a brief explanation for the builtin.

Comment: Downside of partition/4: It does not scale up to constraints.

Comment: @false: because of eager evaluation, I suppose... Definitely CLP(FD) needs more attention from me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by eager evaluation. It is rather this red cut which makes partition/4 unsuitable. Also the clpfd-version is eager, by forcing even/odd decisions.

Comment: @false: in library(apply) I cannot spot the cut. I assume then it's implicit in (->)/2. Could make sense a CLP(FD) *only* Prolog library?

Comment: A clean partition would expect a predicate that give eiher true/false or 1/0. See (this question)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality]