# Even/Odd function in Prolog for Empty List

Tags: prolog

I'm attempting to create an even/odd function in Prolog.

The first parameter is a list of integers, the second parameter is a list of Even numbers, and the last parameter is the list of Odd functions.

This is what I have currently:

```
even_odd([], [], []).
even_odd([H|T], [H|E], O) :-
    0 is X mod 2,
    even_odd(T, E, O).
even_odd([H|T], E, [H|O]) :-
    1 is X mod 2,
    even_odd(T, E, O).
```

This works for every list except for the empty (`[]`) list.

Whenever I try the empty list I get:

```
even_odd([], Even, Odd).
Even = Odd, Odd = [].
```

Instead of:

```
even_odd([], Even, Odd).
Even = [], Odd = [].
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Edit: I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318589/prolog-partition-integer-list-items-by-their-parity) but it didn't work for empty list.

Comment: The output from SWI-Prolog is correct, it's just pointing out that Even and Odd have the same value, which is the empty list. Your program is correct. :)

Comment: @DanielLyons Thank you very much.

Comment: Shouldn't `X` be replaced by `H`?

Comment: Good catch @SamSegers!