# tracing a simple prolog code to fully understand the CUT (!)

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

```
member(X,[X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]):-member(X,T).

delfstocc(X,[X|T],T).
delfstocc(X,[Y|T],[Y|T1]):-delfstocc(X,T,T1),!.

delallocc(X,L,L1):-member(X,L),delfstocc(X,L,R),!,delallocc(X,R,L1);write(L).
```

ـــــــــــ

first , i wrote this code without using the cut ,
 then i tried to put the cut operator after each predicate untill i get the perfect answer
but actually i don't understand how it works after using the cut .
i know that the cut operator stops prolog from proceeding matching ,
however i can't use it correctly ,
so i want help tracing this code
by the way , this code simly delete all occurrences of an element in a list .

Comment: Can you try and format your question? It will be easier to read...

Comment: am sorry i am new on the site , actually that's my first question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as far as cuts are concerned, it is actually handled as follows:

"The goal succeeds and commits Prolog to all the choices made since the parent goal was unified with the head of the clause the cut occurs in".

See also: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0

About deleting from a list: to achieve what you want, your approach is unnecessarily complicated. Here is a more simple solution:

For the empty list, delete always holds true:

```
del([],_X,[]).
```

When the head of the list is the same as the element you are deleting, it does not belong to the other list:

```
del([X|Xs], X, Ys) :- del(Xs, X, Ys).
```

When the head of the list is *not* the same as the element you are deleting, it belongs to the other list:

```
del([X|Xs], Z, [X|Ys]) :- dif(X,Z), del(Xs, X, Ys).
```

(Note: the order of the clauses is significant! Why?)

This solution does not use cuts and attempts backtracking. You could use cuts at the appropriate places to prevent backtracking.

Comment: Nice. For a more efficient approach (with the same nice properties) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality