# breadth first on binary tree - using Semicontext notation

Tags: list, prolog, dcg, dcg-semicontext

I would like to compute list being bfs order on binary tree. Moreover,  it should work in second side - for list it find tree.
Can you give me some hint, so far I have used something like that, of course it doesn't work...

```
bfs(nil) --> [].
bfs(t(X, L, R)), [X] --> bfs(L), bfs(R).
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a Google search for "Prolog BFS"? You'll get [quite a few hits](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=prolog%20bfs&oq=prolog%20bfs&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.5688j0j4). It's going to be more complicated than doing DFS. One approach is to use a queue, which is also used in other languages when developing a BFS method. There's also an interesting presentation in the search list that uses other techniques.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Nevertheless, keep in mind that my case is particular - it is **binary** tree.

Comment: Did you mean closed list or open list ?

Comment: I mean in the list of search results if you click my link. :) The fact that you're dealing with a *binary* tree doesn't change the BFS technique itself. It just changes some of the minor details of the traversal. In fact, it's probably just specialization of the methods shown. There are so many BFS links for prolog in the search I would think at least one of them might specifically do binary trees, but there must be something there that can get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like @repeat came up with a nice DCG solution. I had, in the meantime, come up with a "traditional" queue-based solution that is non-DCG:

```
bfs_tree_list(nil, []).
bfs_tree_list(Tree, List) :-
    bfs_q_list([Tree], List).

bfs_q_list([], []).
bfs_q_list([t(X,L,R)|Qs], [X|Xs]) :-
    enqueue(L, Qs, Q1),
    enqueue(R, Q1, Q2),
    bfs_q_list(Q2, Xs).

% "naive" enqueue using append
enqueue(nil, Q, Q).
enqueue(t(X,L,R), Q1, Q2) :- append(Q1, [t(X,L,R)], Q2).
```

This follows the methodology shown in the links I provided in my comments. It also follows a strict left-to-right traversal ordering which, I believe, is conventional in binary tree traversals. It's a little simpler than those in the links as those are for more general graphs rather than binary trees. The description of what's happening above is simple:

1. Start with the top level in the queue
2. For each element in the queue (until queue is empty)

     (a) Dequeue and accept the current node value
     (b) Enqueue the left and right nodes

The above code yields:

```
| ?- bfs_tree_list(t(3,t(1,nil,t(2,nil,nil)),t(4,nil,nil)), L).

L = [3,1,4,2]

(1 ms) yes
```

And:

```
| ?- bfs_tree_list(Tree, [3,1,4,2]).

Tree = t(3,nil,t(1,nil,t(4,nil,t(2,nil,nil)))) ? a

Tree = t(3,nil,t(1,nil,t(4,t(2,nil,nil),nil)))

Tree = t(3,nil,t(1,t(4,nil,t(2,nil,nil)),nil))

Tree = t(3,nil,t(1,t(4,t(2,nil,nil),nil),nil))

Tree = t(3,nil,t(1,t(4,nil,nil),t(2,nil,nil)))

Tree = t(3,t(1,nil,t(4,nil,t(2,nil,nil))),nil)

Tree = t(3,t(1,nil,t(4,t(2,nil,nil),nil)),nil)

Tree = t(3,t(1,t(4,nil,t(2,nil,nil)),nil),nil)

Tree = t(3,t(1,t(4,t(2,nil,nil),nil),nil),nil)

Tree = t(3,t(1,t(4,nil,nil),t(2,nil,nil)),nil)

Tree = t(3,t(1,nil,nil),t(4,nil,t(2,nil,nil)))

Tree = t(3,t(1,nil,nil),t(4,t(2,nil,nil),nil))

Tree = t(3,t(1,nil,t(2,nil,nil)),t(4,nil,nil))

Tree = t(3,t(1,t(2,nil,nil),nil),t(4,nil,nil))

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

---

Here's a revised version that uses a difference list rather than `append/3`.

```
bfs_tree_list(nil, []).
bfs_tree_list(Tree, List) :-
    bfs_q_list([Tree|T], T, List).

bfs_q_list(Q, T, []) :- Q == T, !.
bfs_q_list([t(X,L,R)|Qs], T, [X|Xs]) :-
    [t(X,L,R)|Qs] \== T,
    enqueue(L, T1, T),
    enqueue(R, NewT, T1),
    bfs_q_list(Qs, NewT, Xs).

enqueue(nil, Q, Q).
enqueue(t(X,L,R), T, [t(X,L,R)|T]).
```

Comment: Could you show me how to realize enqueue with open/difference lists ?

Comment: @HaskellFun I added that version to my answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: What about useless choicepoints left open by `bfs_q_tree//2`?

Comment: @repeat yeah my next step on this is try to eliminate that.

Comment: Enjoy;) Take care that the code still runs in both ways (tree -> list and back).

Comment: @repeat indeed! I thought I was doing good getting it as far as it is. ;) I find that proper removal of a useless choice point is not so easy.

Comment: IMO the key is *restraint*. I tried to elaborate on how indexing can be used to that end (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37353796/4609915). I can recommend the SICStus doc section on "determinacy detection": https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Determinacy-Detection.html

Comment: @repeat thanks a lot for the links. I shall review those. In the meantime, I did some tracing to determine where choice points were occurring, etc, and came up with a solution and modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Those useless choicepoints are gone, but I *do* find the code harder to understand... Also, `bfs_tree_list(nil,[])` still leaves a useless choicepoint.

Comment: Should I add my non-accumulator version as a separate answer?

Comment: @repeat yes, there's a little extra complexity is an artifact of managing the difference list. The elimination of the choice point was done by explicitly checking whether the current queue and the difference tail were the same. Whether it's a separate answer or an addendum to your current answer depends (IMO) on how much of a departure it is from the structure of your current answer. I kept mine together because both were using what I considered to be a "standard" BFS queue method. (Although by the time I tweaked it, I may have thought differently.)

Comment: I think so, too. Structurally, there's next to no difference: accu vs dcg, that's all.

Comment: Here's how you could get rid of the useless choicepoint left behind by `?- bfs_tree_list(nil,[]).`: Define `bfs_tree_list/2` like this: `bfs_tree_list(Tree,List) :- if_(Tree = nil, List = [], bfs_q_list([Tree|T], T, List)).` :)

Comment: @repeat thanks for that suggestion. I was thinking something in those terms. :)

Comment: @repeat it seems like [`if_/3`, `=/3`, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600) should become part of the ISO standard. It's getting to be a pain having to hunt their implementations down in SO posts. :)

Comment: For the time being use `library(reif)`, available for SWI http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl and for SICStus http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl !

Answer (score 4):

This is how you could do it using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) (without semicontexts) and accumulators:

```
tree_bfss(T, Xs) :-
   phrase(bfs1([T]), Xs).

bfs1([]) --> [].                    % done if level is empty           
bfs1([X|Xs]) -->
   step_(X, [], Ts),                % single step
   bfs0_(Xs, Ts).                   % process items in this level

bfs0_([], Ts) -->               
   bfs1(Ts).                        % process next level
bfs0_([X|Xs], Ts0) -->
   step_(X, Ts0, Ts),               % single step
   bfs0_(Xs, Ts).                   % continue with this level

step_(nil, Ts, Ts) --> [].
step_(t(L,M,R), Ts, [R,L|Ts]) -->   % push R and L to the next level
   [M].                             % take care of M right now
```

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- tree_bfss(t(t(nil,1,t(nil,2,nil)),3,t(nil,4,nil)), Xs).
Xs = [3,4,1,2] ? ;
no
```

How about going in the "other" direction?

```
| ?- tree_bfss(T, [3,4,1,2]).
T = t(t(t(t(nil,2,nil),1,nil),4,nil),3,nil) ? ;
T = t(t(t(nil,1,t(nil,2,nil)),4,nil),3,nil) ? ;
T = t(t(nil,4,t(t(nil,2,nil),1,nil)),3,nil) ? ;
T = t(t(nil,4,t(nil,1,t(nil,2,nil))),3,nil) ? ;
T = t(t(t(nil,2,nil),4,t(nil,1,nil)),3,nil) ? ;
T = t(nil,3,t(t(t(nil,2,nil),1,nil),4,nil)) ? ;
T = t(nil,3,t(t(nil,1,t(nil,2,nil)),4,nil)) ? ;
T = t(nil,3,t(nil,4,t(t(nil,2,nil),1,nil))) ? ;
T = t(nil,3,t(nil,4,t(nil,1,t(nil,2,nil)))) ? ;
T = t(nil,3,t(t(nil,2,nil),4,t(nil,1,nil))) ? ;
T = t(t(nil,1,nil),3,t(t(nil,2,nil),4,nil)) ? ;
T = t(t(nil,1,nil),3,t(nil,4,t(nil,2,nil))) ? ;
T = t(t(t(nil,2,nil),1,nil),3,t(nil,4,nil)) ? ;
T = t(t(nil,1,t(nil,2,nil)),3,t(nil,4,nil)) ? ;
no
```

#### Edit

Helpful comments have suggested clarification of the order of the list items:

- Above code does not guarantee any particular order within each single tree level.
- It does ensure that all items of the i<sup>th</sup> level occur before all items of the (i+1)<sup>th</sup> level.

(This has made the implementation slightly simpler.)

Comment: Argh, why is the value in the middle? :)

Comment: @Boris. It felt more natural to me: (1) it resembles the graphical representation, (2) naming the arguments of `t/3` was (a bit) easier: `L`eft, `M`iddle, `R`ight,

Comment: @Boris. Is that conclusive? Or should I rather flip it to `t(M,L,R)` ?

Comment: I think it's more common to express the attributes of a binary tree node as "value, left, right".

Comment: Does your code really produce `[3,4,1,2]` for that tree? I think it should be `[3,1,4,2]` for a correct BFS traversal. Perhaps change `step_(t(L,M,R), Ts, [R,L|Ts])` to `step_(t(L,M,R), Ts, [L,R|Ts])`. :)

Comment: @lurker. It does. I think the order of items (within a level) is unspecified, not necessarily left to right...  Initially, I had the order you are proposing. But the code got a little simpler (by using an accumulator instead of a second difference list). As an alternative, one could use `reverse/2` like so: `bfs0_([], Ts0) --> reverse(Ts0,Ts), bfs1(Ts).` but, then again, I don't think it is required.

Comment: I think BFS of a tree is traditionally left-then-right. I wouldn't think that would affect the structure of the code at all. Viewing the binary tree as a special form of graph, however, it probably wouldn't matter I suppose.

Comment: @lurker. The code structure would stay the same, but an additional argument (or a reverse/2 goal) would be needed...

Comment: @lurker. would you suggest I change it for sake of clarity?

Comment: By just swapping the `L` and `R` as I suggested seems to produce the results I'm referring to. I don't know if it's necessary to change it other than to point out what the intention is. I don't know if everyone else has the same mental paradigm of BFS for binary trees that I do. :)

Comment: @lurker. That does it for this very small tree. In the general case a list difference or an accumulator+reverse is required.

Comment: The value can be wherever you want it to be, it just caught me by surprise. It is a bit unconventional. See the comment by @lurker: it is not "left, middle, right", it is "node value, left subtree, right subtree". You see this exact order also in say `struct tnode { T value; struct tnode * left; struct tnode * right; };`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra comments to the answer. It's made me think: a binary tree truly is just a specialized graph, so this algorithm meets all the requirements of a BFS search. Traditionally, in CS literature, binary tree branches are described left to right and often traversed that way in order to provide a canonical way to uniquely represent the tree in a list form. But as far as the act of traversing is concerned, the choosing an arbitrary of L versus R doesn't impact the algorithm's property of visiting each node exactly once and in true BFS fashion.

Comment: Another thought... It might be better to stick to a given, stated traversal convention. If it considers the left versus right ordering arbitrary, then that begs the question whether the solution should generate all such possible results (in either direction).