# filter list into separate lists

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

I need to filter the list `[#,d,e,#,f,g]` such that I get the output as `[[d,e],[f,g]]` ,
I am stuck while creating a new list every time I encounter '#' is there a way to do this?
I tried the code below,

```
filterL([],List) :-[].
filterL([Head|Tail],X) :-
   (  Head \='#'->
      append(X,Head,List),
      filterL(Tail,List)
   ;  filterL(Tail,X)
   ).
```

Comment: `%` is a comment, so use quotes like `['%',d,e,'%',f,g]`

Comment: ... otherwise it is not clear what your program means. `List` in the first clause does not make any sense. You probably want a predicate of arity 3 not 2. There are no return statements in Prolog.

Comment: @false it should just return an empty list.

Comment: So `[]`, `[#]`, `[#,#]`, `[#,#,#]` ... all give `[]`?

Comment: @false yes, if input is[#,a,b,#,#,c,d] then it should give[[a,b],[c,d]].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not very well defined. Are empty sequences allowed or not?  Shall `[#]` be related to `[[],[]]` (there is an empty sequence before and after) or `[]`? You say it should be `[]`. So:

```
list_splitbyhash(Xs, Xss) :-
   phrase(splitby(Xss,#), Xs).

splitby([],_E) -->
    [].
splitby(Xss,E) -->
    [E],
    splitby(Xss,E).
splitby([Xs|Xss],E) -->
    {Xs = [_|_]},
    all_seq(dif(E),Xs),
    splitby(Xss,E).

all_seq(_, []) --> [].
all_seq(C_1, [C|Cs]) -->
   [C],
   {call(C_1,C)},
   all_seq(C_1, Cs).
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another version, which uses an even more general approach:

```
list_splitbyhash(Xs, Xss) :-
   phrase(by_split(=(#), Xss), Xs).

=(X,X,true).
=(X,Y,false) :- dif(X,Y).

by_split(_C_2, []) --> [].
by_split(C_2, Xss) -->
   [E],
   {call(C_2,E,T)},
   (  { T = true },
      by_split(C_2, Xss)
   |  { T = false, Xss = [[E|Xs]|Xss1] },
      all_seq(callfalse(C_2),Xs),
      el_or_nothing(C_2),
      by_split(C_2, Xss1)
   ).

callfalse(C_2,E) :-
   call(C_2,E,false).

el_or_nothing(_) -->
   call(nil).
el_or_nothing(C_2), [E] -->
   [E],
   {call(C_2,E,true)}.

nil([], []).
```

With [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+lambda), this can be expressed more compactly. Instead of

```
   all_seq(callfalse(C_2),Xs)
```

and the definition for `callfalse/3`, one can now write

```
   all_seq(C_2+\F^call(C_2,F,false))
```

Comment: Is it possible to get only one solution from the number of solutions produced by prolog predicate? For e.g..list_splitbyhash([#,1,2,3,#],X). gives only [[1,2,3]].

Comment: You are right! Fixed, even if this is no longer that nice as it used to be.

Comment: Thanks , I was just curious.

Comment: list_splitbyhash([k,#,l,m,#,#,N],X). gives, X = [[k], [l, m], [N]],
dif(N, #)., Is it possible to ignore 'dif(N,#)' from the output?

Comment: @sand: That would be incorrect! Also, please look at the different answers, for there are many!

Comment: What if I only want the last output? Is there a way I can get it without others? For example `[A,#,B]` I'd like '[[A],[B]]'.

Answer (score 2):

With meta-predicate [`splitlistIf/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and the reified equality predicate [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915), the task at hand becomes a *one-liner*---that is both efficient and **logically pure**!

```
?- splitlistIf(=(#),[#,d,e,#,f,g],Xs).
Xs = [[d,e],[f,g]].                      % succeeds deterministically
```

As the code is **monotone**, logical soundness is ensured even for quite general queries:

```
?- Xs = [A,B,C], splitlistIf(=(X),Xs,Yss).
Xs = [A,B,C],     X=A ,     X=B ,     X=C , Yss = [       ] ;
Xs = [A,B,C],     X=A ,     X=B , dif(X,C), Yss = [    [C]] ;
Xs = [A,B,C],     X=A , dif(X,B),     X=C , Yss = [  [B]  ] ;
Xs = [A,B,C],     X=A , dif(X,B), dif(X,C), Yss = [  [B,C]] ;
Xs = [A,B,C], dif(X,A),     X=B ,     X=C , Yss = [[A]    ] ;
Xs = [A,B,C], dif(X,A),     X=B , dif(X,C), Yss = [[A],[C]] ;
Xs = [A,B,C], dif(X,A), dif(X,B),     X=C , Yss = [[A,B]  ] ;
Xs = [A,B,C], dif(X,A), dif(X,B), dif(X,C), Yss = [[A,B,C]].
```