# How to split a list filled with logic variables in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate `split(List, Pivot, Result)` holds when Result is a list of sublists that List divided by Pivot. For example `split([A, B, '#', C, '#', D], '#', [[A, B], [C], [D]])` is true. Note that the elements are lists with logic variables.

I asked a question about how to do this to lists which do not have logic variables as elements. Here's the answer:

```
split(L,P,R):-split(L,P,[],R).
split([],_,[],[]).
split([],_,S,[S]) :- S \= [].
split([P|T],P,[],R) :- split(T,P,[],R).
split([P|T],P,L,[L|R]) :- L \= [], split(T,P,[],R).
split([H|T],P,S,R) :- H \= P, append(S, [H], S2), split(T,P,S2,R).
```

However this does not work with the lists which have logic variables as elements. Any suggestions to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter list into separate lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439058/filter-list-into-separate-lists)

Comment: I can't understand the answer of that question. There are a lot of features that I've never seen before. I tried the solution but couldn't understand what I saw.

Comment: your problem looks like `join`, have you thought about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very nearly there.

Consider this slightly modified version:

```
split(L, P, R) :- split(L, P, [], R).
split([], _P, [], []) :- !.
split([], _P, Acc, [Acc]).
split([X|Xs], P, Acc, Result) :-
    X \== P, !,
    append(Acc, [X], NewAcc),
    split(Xs, P, NewAcc, Result).
split([_X|Xs], P, [], Result) :- !, split(Xs, P, [], Result).
split([_X|Xs], P, Acc, [Acc|Result]) :- split(Xs, P, [], Result).
```

This implementation relies on the accumulator as you'd tried, but simply shunts the accumulator into the result list as soon as the list item doesn't match the pivot using [`\==/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%3D%3D)/2).

Comment: Umm.. This generate `[]`, for example `?- split(['#', A,'#',B,ASD,D,'#'], '#', X).
X = [[], [A], [B, ASD, D], []] .` It should be `[[A], [B, ASD, D]]`. Can you fix it?