# How to split list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate `split(List, Pivot, Result)` holds when `Result` is a list of sublists that `List` divided by `Pivot`. For example `split(['_', '_', '#', '_', '#', '_'], '#', [['_','_'], ['_'], ['_']])` is `true`.

My code is like this and it doesn't work:

```
split(List, Pivot, Result) :-
split(List, Pivot, _, _, Result).

split(List, Pivot, Left, Right, X|Xs) :-
    append(Left, [Pivot|Right], List),
    !,
    member(Pivot, Right)
    ->  X = [Left],
        split(Right, Pivot, _, _, Xs)
    ;   X = [[Left]|[Right]].
```

I don't think my approach is clever either. Can someone give me some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
split(L,P,R):-split(L,P,[],R).
split([],_,[],[]).
split([],_,S,[S]) :- S \= [].
split([P|T],P,[],R) :- split(T,P,[],R).
split([P|T],P,L,[L|R]) :- L \= [], split(T,P,[],R).
split([H|T],P,S,R) :- H \= P, append(S, [H], S2), split(T,P,S2,R).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Mm7wCZ)

`split/4` predicate adds a parameter at position 3 which means "list constructed so far". `split/3` is a simple redirection with the "list so far" set to `[]`.

Clauses on lines 2 and 4 handle situations when two `Pivot`s are in a row, and when the pivot is detected at the end of the sequence. These clauses prevent insertion of empty lists.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your answer, but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) and get the job done in no time, simply by using the right tools!

Let's use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`splitlistIf/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and the [reified equality predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality) [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915) in a query:

```
?- Xs = ['_','_',#,'_',#,'_'], splitlistIf(=(#),Xs,Ys).
Xs = [ '_','_' ,#,'_',#,'_' ]
Ys = [['_','_'], ['_'],['_']].      % succeeds deterministically
```