# How to construct a list of positions for a certain element in a main list?

Tags: prolog

How can I write a predicate `list_pos(B,E,L)`, that returns the positions of `E` in `B`, in a list named `L` (considering that the first element of `B` has position=0), i tried writing such a program but it didn't run successfully.Thanks

Comment: Please show what you tried to write, it would be a good way to start looking at your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which is slightly more general than @Jerome's:

```
list_pos(Xs, E, Ps) :-
   ( ground(Xs) -> true ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) ),
   ( length(Xs,_) -> true ; throw(error(type_error(list,Xs),_)) ),
   bagof(P, nth0(P, Xs, E), Ps).

?- list_pos([a,b,c,c,a,a], E, Rs).
   E = a, Rs = [0, 4, 5]
;  E = b, Rs = [1]
;  E = c, Rs = [2, 3].
```

So you do not even need to indicate the precise element you want. Instead, you ask:

> What are the occurrences of the various elements?

This can be generalized even one step further ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general, and pure solution - I will put a bounty here to fit this into more convenient abstractions.

```
list_pos(Xs, E, Ps) :-
   list_pos(Xs, E, Ps, 0).

list_pos([], _E, [], _P).
list_pos([X|Xs], X, [P0|Ps], P0) :-
   P1 is P0 + 1,
   list_pos(Xs, X, Ps, P1).
list_pos([X|Xs], E, Ps, P0) :-
   dif(X, E),        % element must be different
   P1 is P0 + 1,
   list_pos(Xs, X, Ps, P1).
```

And here is a more compact and efficient way for `list_pos/4` using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868) and reïfied equality [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/772868). Prolog's `if_/3` is a bit different to traditional if-then-else, for it can opt for *both* the Then *and* the Else. Maybe just try out the `if_/3`:

```
?- if_( X=Y, Diagnosis=equal, Diagnosis=inequal).
   X = Y, Diagnosis = equal
;  Diagnosis = inequal, dif(X, Y).
```

Informally, what we ask here is:

> Are `X` and `Y` equal or not?

And the Prolog answer is not just yes or no, but:

> Yes, they are equal, if they are equal

**AND**

> No, they are not equal, if they are different

Sounds irritating? Well, if we ask such general questions that do not contain sufficient information, we should not be surprised to get similarly general answers!

```
list_pos([], _E, [], _P).
list_pos([X|Xs], E, Ps0, P0) :-
   P1 is P0+1,
   if_(X = E, Ps0 = [P0|Ps1], Ps0 = Ps1),
   list_pos(Xs, E, Ps1, P1).
```

And now, lets try something very general!

> How must a list `[X,Y,Z]` look like such that any element `E` occurs in it twice?

```
?- list_pos([X,Y,Z],E,[A,B]).
   X = Y, Y = E, % ... the first two are the same
   A = 0, B = 1,
   dif(Z, E)     % ... but the last is different
;  X = Z, Z = E, % ... the first and last are the same
   A = 0, B = 2,
   dif(Y, E)     % ... but the middle element is different
;  Y = Z, Z = E, % ... the last two are the same
   A = 1, B = 2,
   dif(X, E)     % ... and the first is different.
;  false.
```

Note that these answers comprise the **full generality** of all possible three element lists! All of them have been included.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @false and @Jerome I am learning a lot. Nevertheless, I will post my efforts:

```
    list_pos(List,Elem,Result) :-
            list_pos(List,Elem,[],-1,R),
            reverse(R,Result),
            !.

    list_pos([],_,W,_,W).
    list_pos([X|Xs],X,Zs,P,R) :-
            Pos is P + 1,
            list_pos(Xs,X,[Pos|Zs],Pos,R).
    list_pos([_|Xs],Y,Zs,P,R) :-
            Pos is P + 1,
            list_pos(Xs,Y,Zs,Pos,R).
```

Ex.

```
    ?- list_pos([],a,R).
    R = [].

    ?- list_pos([a,c,a,d,e,f],a,R).
    R = [0, 2].

    ?- list_pos([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],g,R).
    R = [6].

    ?- list_pos([a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],a,R).
    R = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
```

Comment: This way of using the cut is incorrect and inefficient.  For correctness, `list_pos([1],1,[]).` succeeds, but it should fail.

Comment: The `Zs` list can be described directly,without reversing it later on.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @false. Although I don't know how, I will keep in mind (for study) that the Zs can be described in order without reversing.

Comment: Please look at my new answer for this! That's a common beginner's error :-)

Comment: @false, yes I saw it. I have copied it to my notes to study on the bus on my way home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
    list_pos(1,Match,[Match|_]).
    list_pos(Pos,Element,[_|Tail]) :-
             list_pos(P,Element,Tail),
             Pos is P + 1.
```

Ex.

```
    ?- list_pos(B,a,[a]).
    B = 1 .

    ?- list_pos(B,a,[b,a]).
    B = 2 .

    ?- list_pos(B,a,[b,c,d,e,a,f]).
    B = 5 .
```

Answer (score 0):

To construct a list of all the results, use `findall`:

```
list_pos(List, Element, Result) :-
  findall(Position, nth0(Position, List, Element), Result).
```

Comment: Add a saftety check in front of findall like: `( ground(List+Element) -> true ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) )`

Comment: I believe it's a good thing that error checking is present in the discussion (in your comment, and in your answer). But I also believe it's a good thing that an uncluttered simplified solution is available among the answers. It has some pedagogical merits.