# Count and remove the successive occurrences of the first element in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I want to count and remove the successive occurrences of the first element in a list.

```
?- count([1,1,1,2,2,1], N, X, L). 
N = 3, X = 1, L = [2,2,1].               % expected answer
```

I try this:

```
count([],0,_,[]).
count([X|T],N,X,L) :-
   !,
   select(X,[X|T],K), 
   L is K,
   count(T,N1,X,L), 
   N is N1+1.
```

Comment: What do you expect for `count([1,1,1,2], N, X, L)`? I don't understand why  in your example `L` is not `[1,2,2]`.

Comment: for   count([1,1,1,2], N, X, L)   i expect  L=[2], N =3, X= 1, that means we have 3 time 1, and in my example we have 3 time 1, and if we remove all of them from the list, we will have L=[2,2,1].

Comment: What about `count([1,2], N, X, L)`?   Really `L = [2]`?

Comment: Yes  L =[2], X =1, N = 1, and for count([1]), we will have L=[], N=1, X=1

Comment: your code `select(X,[X|T],K )` is rather strange: select/3 is usually called with select(X, Domain, Without_X), that is, X position **unknown** in Domain list. In the end, it reduces **L** to **T**. Nothing other !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an eager attempt:

```
count([X,X|T],N,X,L) :-
    !, count([X|T],M,X,L), N is M+1.
count([X|T],1,X,T) :- !.
count(L,0,_,L).
```

yields

```
?- count([1,1,1,2,2,1], N, X, L).
N = 3,
X = 1,
L = [2, 2, 1].
```

*edit* since we have an integer domain, an attempt with CLP(FD) - mixed (?) to Prolog eager evaluation

```
initials_count([X,X|T],N,X,L) :-
    N #= M+1,
    initials_count([X|T],M,X,L).
initials_count([X|T],N,E,T) :-
    N #<==> X #= E.
```

should be called like

```
?- once(initials_count([1,1,1,2,2,1], N, X, L)).
```

(tested with SWI-Prolog)

In GnuProlog, should be

```
initials_count([X|T],N,E,T) :-
    N #<=> X #= E.
```

If you want to avoid the problem illustrated in comment by @false, a refinement of the last clause (of first predicate) could be

```
count(L,0,E,L) :- L == [] ; L == [F|_], F \== E.
```

Comment: Both definitions are incorrectly succeeding for the following cases: `?- count([a],0,a,L).`  and `?- initials_count([1],0,2,[]).`

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you could do it using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality/29708684):

```
count([], 0, _, []).
count([E|Es], N, E, L) :-
   skip_(Es, 1,N, E, L).

skip_([], N,N, _, []).
skip_([E|Es], N0,N, X, Xs) :-
   if_(E = X,
       ( N1 is N0+1, skip_(Es,N1,N,X,Xs) ),
       ( N0 = N,     Xs = [E|Es] )).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- count([1,1,1,2], N, X, L).
N = 3, X = 1, L = [2].

?- count([1,1,1,2,2,1], N, X, L).
N = 3, X = 1, L = [2,2,1].

?- count([1], N, X, L).
N = X, X = 1, L = [].

?- J = [_,_,_], count(J, N, X, L).
   J = [X, X, X], N = 3, L = []
;  J = [X, X,_A], N = 2, L = [_A]   , dif(_A,X)
;  J = [X,_A,_B], N = 1, L = [_A,_B], dif(_A,X).
```

Note that `count/4` can handle lists containing non-integers just as well:

```
?- count([a,a,a,b,b,c], N, X, L).
N = 3, X = a, L = [b,b,c].
```

Comment: All maximally determinate!

Answer (score 3):

```
count([], 0, _, []).
count(J, N, X, L) :-
   J = [X|_],
   append(Xs, L, J),
   startsnot_with(L, X),
   maplist(=(X), Xs),
   length(Xs, N).

startsnot_with([], _).
startsnot_with([E|_], X) :-
   dif(E, X).

| ?- J = [_,_,_], count(J, N, X, L).
   J = [X,_A,_B], N = 1, L = [_A,_B], dif(_A,X)
;  J = [X,X,_A],  N = 2, L = [_A], dif(_A,X)
;  J = [X,X,X],   N = 3, L = []
;  false.
```

Comment: ?- count([1,1,1,2,2,1],N,X,L).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,dif/2),startsnot_with/2)
| ?-

Comment: What Prolog are you using? GNU?

Comment: the answer that i proposed works, but the problem is L, i can't get L correctly.