# List consisting of each element of another List repeated twice Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have to write a predicate: double(X,Y) to be true when Y is the list consisting of each element of X
 repeated twice (e.g. double([a,b],[a,a,b,b]) is true).

I ended with sth like this:

```
double([],[]).
double([T],List) :- double([H|T],List).
double([H|T],List) :- count(H, List, 2).
```

Its working fine for lists like [a,a,b] but it shouldnt... please help.

And i need help with another predicate: repeat(X,Y,N) to be true when Y is the list consisting of each element of X
repeated N times (e.g. repeat([a,b], [a,a,a,b,b,b],3) is true).

Comment: HINT: `[H,H|T]` represents a list where `H` occurs twice in the front of the list.

Comment: `double([X|Xs], [X,X|Ys]) :- double(Xs, Ys).
double([], []).` Working, thanks. But what with repeat predicate?

Comment: Regarding that other predicate... how about posting another question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double([],[]).
double([I|R],[I,I|RD]) :-
    double(R,RD).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could realize that "repeat" predicate you suggested in the question:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality/29708684) we define:

```
each_n_reps([E|Es], N) :-
   aux_n_reps(Es, E, 1, N).

aux_n_reps([], _, N, N).               % internal auxiliary predicate
aux_n_reps([E|Es], E0, N0, N) :-
   if_(E0 = E,
       ( N0 #< N, N1 #= N0+1 ),        % continue current run
       ( N0 #= N, N1 #= 1 )),          % start new run
   aux_n_reps(Es, E, N1, N).
```

Sample queries<sup>1</sup> using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
?- each_n_reps(Xs, 3).
   Xs = [_A,_A,_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_A,_A,_B,_B,_B]         , dif(_A,_B)
;  Xs = [_A,_A,_A,_B,_B,_B,_C,_C,_C], dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C)
...
```

How about fair enumeration?

```
?- length(Xs, _), each_n_reps(Xs, N).
   N = 1, Xs = [_A]
;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_A]
;  N = 1, Xs = [_A,_B]      , dif(_A,_B)
;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_A,_A]
;  N = 1, Xs = [_A,_B,_C]   , dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C)
;  N = 4, Xs = [_A,_A,_A,_A]
;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_A,_B,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  N = 1, Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D], dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C), dif(_C,_D)
...
```

How can `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` be split into runs of equal length?

```
?- each_n_reps([A,B,C,D,E,F], N).
   N = 6,     A=B ,     B=C ,     C=D ,     D=E ,     E=F 
;  N = 3,     A=B ,     B=C , dif(C,D),     D=E ,     E=F
;  N = 2,     A=B , dif(B,C),     C=D , dif(D,E),     E=F
;  N = 1, dif(A,B), dif(B,C), dif(C,D), dif(D,E), dif(E,F).
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1**: Answers were reformatted to improve readability.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ok for repeat/3 i have sth like this:

```
repeat1([],[],0).
repeat1([A|B],[X|T],Y):- repeat1(B,T,Z), Y is 1+Z.
repeat1([A1|B],[X1|T], Z) :- A1\=A, X1\=X, repeat1(B,T,Z).
```

Comment: *Very* brittle. In cases of insufficient instantation your code gives logically incorrect answers without fair warning...