# Prolog: Add to list all members of another list that have specific property

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to create a rule `F(C,L)` where `C` and `L` are integer lists. `L` contains the index number (starting from 1) of all the elements of `C` that are equal to `43`. My code is shown below. When I try `F([43,42,43,42,42,43],L)`. it returns true. What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
F(C,L) :-
    forall(
        (
            member(X,C),
            X=43,
            nth1(N,C,X)
        ),
        member(N,L)
    ).
```

Comment: Prolog predicate cannot start with a capital letter, So the code you're showing must generate an error and not even run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it step by step:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_contains_at1s(Elements, Member, Positions) :-
   list_contains_at_index1(Elements, Member, Positions, 1).

list_contains_at_index1([], _, [], _).
list_contains_at_index1([E|Es], E, [I1|Is], I1) :-
   I2 #= I1+1,
   list_contains_at_index1(Es, E, Is, I2).
list_contains_at_index1([E|Es], X, Is, I1) :-
   dif(X, E),
   I2 #= I1+1,
   list_contains_at_index1(Es, X, Is, I2).
```

Sample query with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- list_contains_at1s([43,42,43,42,42,43], 43, Positions).
   Positions = [1,3,6]
;  false.                                % left-over choicepoint
```

Comment: Don't extend - add a new answer, preferably with a performance comparison.

Answer (score 3):

The  [code by @CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163423/4609915) works, but **only** when used with *sufficient instantiation*.

```
?- f([43,42,43,42,42,43], Ps).
Ps = [1,3,6].                              % ok

?- f([A,B], Ps).
Ps = [1,2].                                % BAD

?- f(_, _).
**LOOPS**                                  % BAD: doesn't terminate
```

To safeguard against problems like these we can use
[`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915) like so:

```
f_safe(C, L) :-
   iwhen(ground(C), findall(X,nth1(X,C,43),L)).
```

Let's re-run above queries with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- f_safe([43,42,43,42,42,43], Ps).
Ps = [1,3,6].                              % still ok

?- f_safe([A,B], Ps).                      % BETTER
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- f_safe(_, _).                           % BETTER
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error apart, you're doing it more complex than needed. Keep it simpler, and use findall/3 instead of forall/2. The latter cannot be used to instantiate variables *outside* its scope.

```
f(C,L) :- findall(X, nth1(X,C,43), L).
```

Answer (score 2):

While [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165020/4609915) preserves [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity), it shows some inefficiency in queries like:

```
?- list_contains_at1s([43,42,43,42,42,43], 43, Ps).
Ps = [1,3,6] ;       % <------ SWI toplevel indicates lingering choicepoint
false.
```

In above query the lingering choicepoint is guaranteed to be useless: we know that above use case can never yield more than one solution.

#### Method 1: explicit indexing and extra helper predicate

The [earlier definition of `list_contains_at_index1/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165020/4609915)  has **two** recursive clauses—one covering the "equal" case, the other one covering the "not equal" case.

Note that these two recursive clauses of `list_contains_at_index1/4` are mutually exclusive, because `(=)/2` and `dif/2` are mutually exclusive.

How can we exploit this?

By utilizing  [first-argument indexing](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Indexing-Overview.html#Indexing-Overview) together with the [**reified** term equality predicate `(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality)!

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

list_contains_at_index1([], _, [], _).
list_contains_at_index1([E|Es], X, Is0, I1) :-
   =(E, X, T),                              % (=)/3
   equal_here_at0_at(T, I1, Is0, Is),
   I2 #= I1+1,
   list_contains_at_index1(Es, X, Is, I2).

equal_here_at0_at(true , I1, [I1|Is], Is).  % index on the truth value ...
equal_here_at0_at(false,  _,     Is , Is).  % ... of reified term equality
```

#### Method 2: implicit indexing, no extra helper predicate, using `if_/3`

For more concise code we can put `if_/3` to good use:

```
list_contains_at_index1([], _, [], _).
list_contains_at_index1([E|Es], X, Is0, I1) :-
   if_(E = X, Is0 = [I1|Is], Is0 = Is),
   I2 #= I1+1,
   list_contains_at_index1(Es, X, Is, I2).
```

---

If we re-run above query with new improved code ...

```
?-  list_contains_at1s([43,42,43,42,42,43], 43, Positions).
Positions = [1, 3, 6].
```

... we see that the query now *succeeds deterministically*. Mission accomplished!